# Simple Assignment Help: Calling the function to pass it a parameter and to get its return value

Tags: javascript, html, function, scope, return

## Assignment HELP: "Calling the function to pass it a parameter and to get its return value"

Hi, I am a complete newbie just starting out with javascript in Uni and needed help with this part of my assignment regarding "Calling the function to pass it a parameter and to get its return value"

These are the detailed instruction given for the assignment:

1. Declaring a function with parameters and return value 
   •Inside the  tags, add a function named getInput() with a parameter named (request).

Give it two statements.

- The first statement prompts the user for whatever the request is and stores it in a variable called message.

-The second statement returns the message to wherever the function has been called from

2. Calling the function to pass it a parameter and to get its return value

Now add a function named testParamsReturn() that

•Declares a variable named "firstName"

•In a single line:
-Calls the getInput() function
-Gives the call a parameter of “first name” (as a string).
-Assigns the value returned by the function to firstName.

•Declares a variable named "secondName"

•In a single line:
-Calls the getInput() function 
-Gives the call a parameter of “second name”
-Assigns the value returned for the function to "secondName".

Alerts “Testing a function with parameters and a return value of ”and appends both the variables you have declared in the function

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<section>
<input type="button" value="Function with Parameters and Return Value"     onClick="testParamsReturn()">
</section>
<script>
function getInput(request){
var message = "Enter details here";
return message;
}
function testParamsReturn(){
var firstName = "Name1";
function getInput("first_name") return firstName;
var secondName = "Name2";
function getInput("second_name") return secondName;
alert ("Testing a function with parameters and a return value of" + firstName + secondName);
}
```

The other section works just fine but this function has disabled me to click any button from the file.

Comment: `function getInput("first_name") return firstName;`

You can't set string in params, may be you mean

`function getInput(firstName) return "first_name";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All steps I described within code, hope you this will help ;)

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <section> 
      <h1> on page must be H1 tag, in section must be H1-6 tag.</h1>
      <input type="button" value="Function with Parameters and Return Value" onclick="testParamsReturn()">
    </section>
  </body>
  <script>
    // Inside the tags
    
    /* Declaring a function with parameters and return value   */
    // add a function named getInput() with a parameter named (request).
    function getInput(request){
      // The first statement prompts the user for whatever the request
      // is and stores it in a variable called message.
      var message = prompt(request);
      
      // The second statement returns the message
      return message;
    }
    
    // Now add a function named testParamsReturn() that
    function testParamsReturn(){
      // •Declares a variable named "firstName"
      var firstName;
      
      // In a single line: -Calls the getInput() function -Gives the call a parameter of “first name” (as a string). -Assigns the value returned by the function to firstName.
      firstName = getInput('first name');

    
      // •Declares a variable named "secondName"
      var secondName;
      
      // •In a single line: -Calls the getInput() function -Gives the call a parameter of “second name” -Assigns the value returned for the function to "secondName".
      secondName = getInput('second name');

      // Alerts
      alert (
        // “Testing a function with parameters and a return value of ”
        "Testing a function with parameters and a return value of " + 
        // appends both the variables you have declared in the function
        firstName + 
        ' ' +
        secondName
       );
    } 
  </script>
</html>
```